# Firebase Ui Paging adapter's notifyDataSetChanged not updating the RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, firebaseui

I added swipe to delete to the Firebase Ui Paging RecyclersView and it works fine, when i swipe it deletes it from firestore but then when i call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the UI nothing changes.

I tried using `notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.adapterPosition)` and it removes it from the recyclerView but then it duplicates the next view.

What am i doing wrong here?

Here is my adapter:

```
class SearchAdapter(options:FirestorePagingOptions<Post>, private val clickListener: (Post) -> Unit):FirestorePagingAdapter<Post, SearchAdapter.ViewHolder>(options) {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder.from(parent)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, model: Post) {
    holder.bind(model, clickListener)
}

override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)

    val helper = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean {
            return false
        }
        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            currentList?.snapshot()?.get(viewHolder.adapterPosition)?.reference?.delete()
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
    ItemTouchHelper(helper).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
}

class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: SearchPostItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
    fun bind(post : Post, clickListener: (Post)-> Unit) {
        binding.post = post
        binding.root.setOnClickListener { clickListener(post) }
        binding.executePendingBindings()

    }
    companion object{
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup) :ViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = SearchPostItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(binding)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the list name you are passing to adapter?

Comment: you can try to `adapter.startListening()` so that the adapter can be updated automatically without the need to remove it manually

Answer (score 0):

Say if the list you passing to your adapter is simpleList
Then onSwipe, you could do

```
        simpleList.remove(viewHolder.adapterPosition);
        notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.adapterPosition);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(viewHolder.adapterPosition, simpleList.size());
```